# Heap out of memory when compiling node.js from source

Tags: node.js

In my ubuntu machine I'm trying to compile node js from source but it's showing me heap out of memory after a while. How do i fix this?

Comment: How much memory do you have in your build machine? It might be not sufficient!

Comment: I'm running ubuntu server and it's a test environment so I thought 1gb will do. I compiled it earlier but when I tried to compile with --debug in ./configure problem occurred.

Comment: I'm wondering how much memory it can take? Node is not that much of a big package right! So what I'm missing here? And by the way I am new comer.

Comment: I would recommend at least 2GB, preferably more if possible as a developer machine.

Comment: I just tried but no good.. V8 Internal Heap Is close to out of memory.. :(